# Twilio Connect problems

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I'm trying to implement Twilio Connect to allow users to use their phone numbers with my app.

1. In the Twilio console, I see ACd8e3e060b587765318760d5bcd05e3b0 as my Account Sid. However, when I connected a Twilio Connect app to my account, it redirects me to an authorization page with a totally different Account Sid: ACbab18d9990e7af4a42feb51c96cc136f. The problem is that this Account Sid does not have any Incoming Phone Numbers. I provided all the required permissions, how do I use it?
2. According to the documentation:

When a user revokes permission to your Connect App, Twilio will make an HTTP request to the DeauthorizeCallbackURL. You should update your user database to reflect this.

Where can I revoke permission? Is there some list of Connect Apps which I allowed to use with my account?

Comment: I work at Twilio and I can't find either of those accounts... Can you explain the setup a bit more too, which account did you build the connect app with, which account did you try to connect to the connect app?

Comment: I contacted to Twilio support. We added phone search/phone buy functions to our app. So user can buy numbers from our website and use them for sending sms.

Comment: Did you manage to sort things out with Twilio support then?

Comment: List of connected Connect Apps is here: https://www.twilio.com/console/usage/authorized-app. I managed to find a Revoke Access button on an app page. However, it returns a 500 error and does not send any requests to my Deauthorize url. The solution is: on application connect I create a subaccount inside my app, buy phone numbers using it and just close the subaccount using REST API when user presses Disconnect on my website.

Comment: Yes, after reading documentation and testing I found a solution.

Comment: Excellent! Glad to hear it! :)